# Code to Open File, Select All and Copy

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that will open up a .txt file and select and then copy the data in the .txt file.  I am able to open the .txt file but what I am not able to do is create a script to open, select and copy at the same time and in the same script line.

Here are some code examples that I have tried:

```bsh
Invoke-Item adddata.txt; object.SendKeys "^(a)"
```

```bsh
Invoke-Item adddata.txt; WshShell.SendKeys "^"; WshShell.SendKeys "a"
```

```bsh
Invoke-Item adddata.txt; WshShell.SendKeys "{^}a"
```

What happens is the file does open up but nothing selects/copies on either example.

Comment: So you are just trying to get the contents of a file?

Comment: Yes but I'm wanting to be able to paste it to an Excel workbook manually.  Would prefer to have it on the clipboard.

Comment: Because you want to paste into Excel, an example of your file data would be nice. Could you add that to your question?

Answer (score 8):

I think the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) cmdlet is what you should be using:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\ExampleFolder\adddata.txt" | clip
```

Comment: The above code did pull the data but after several times checking I noticed it wasn't getting all of the data.  Is there a way to copy the data to the clipboard?  I should have put that into the opening post.

Comment: If you're having any extra issues, you can add `-Raw` switch with `Get-Content`. Instead of it retrieving the data as an `array of strings` it retrieves it `line by line`. Example: `Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\ExampleFolder\adddata.txt" | clip `

Answer (score 1):

I think php123's answer does the job, however because your paste target is Excel and if the data in your file is in columns with a delimiter and  you can improve the final result. You need to use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to convert to an object and then use the `ConvertTo-Csv` to turn you object into a tab delimited string which will then paste nicely into Excel. Something like this assuming your file is comma separated:

```
Import-Csv "C:\ExampleFolder\adddata.txt" -Delimiter ',' | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" | clip
```